# Angular display table header only once and hide header if no data

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am using Angular 5.

When typeId is equal to 3, I would like to display table header only once.

And also when none of data’s typeId is equal to 3, I want to hide the whole table, do not show table header any more.

Please see my code and data below:

Code:

```
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let attachment of data.Data.Summary.Attachment">
        <ng-container *ngIf="attachment.typeId=='3'">  
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let attachment of data.Data.Summary.Attachment">
            <tr *ngIf="attachment.typeId=='3'">  
                <td>{{ attachment.file }}</td>
                <td>{{ attachment.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ attachment.date }}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>      
</table>
```

Data:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Summary": {
            "Attachment": [
              {
                "typeId": "3",
                "file": "a.pdf",
                "description": "File A",
                "date": "05/03/2017"
              },
              {
                "typeId": "3",
                "file": "b.pdf",
                "description": "File B",
                "date": "05/03/2017"
              },
              {
                "typeId": "1",
                "file": "c.pdf",
                "description": "File C",
                "date": "05/03/2017"
              },
              {
                "typeId": "3",
                "file": "d.pdf",
                "description": "File D",
                "date": "05/03/2017"
              }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
File       Description    Date
a.pdf      File A         05/03/2017
b.pdf      File B         05/03/2017
d.pdf      File D         05/03/2017
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `*ngIf` to include or exclude. For example, `<div *ngIf="false">this will not show</div>` `<div *ngIf="true">this will show</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an "angular" problem, more a javascript problem. In your component, you can create a method `isHeaderVisible()` which decides if the header should be visible or not and use that. Something like:

```
isHeaderVisible() {
  return this.data.Data.Summary.Attachment.some(attachment => attachment.typeId === '3')
}
```

Separately, it'd probably be better to do your data filtering in your component, rather than your component's template. So do something like

```
visibleAttachments() {
  return this.data.Data.Summary.Attachment.filter(attachment => attachment.typeId === '3')
}
```

Put them together and your template might look like:

```
<table>
    <thead *ngIf="isHeaderVisible()">
      <tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let attachment of visibleAttachments()">  
        <td>{{ attachment.file }}</td>
        <td>{{ attachment.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ attachment.date }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>      
</table>
```

Or you could simply do `<thead *ngIf="visibleAttachments().length > 0">` and get rid of `isHeaderVisible()`. And at this point, you might as well move the `*ngIf` to the `<table>` element instead of the `<thead>` element, because it sounds like you only want to display this table if an attachment with `typeId === '3'` exists.

So:

```
<table *ngIf="visibleAttachments().length > 0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let attachment of visibleAttachments()">  
        <td>{{ attachment.file }}</td>
        <td>{{ attachment.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ attachment.date }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>      
</table>
```

Comment: In most situations it'd also be wise to use a cached value of `visibleAttachments()` so that you're not recomputing the value each change detection cycle -- but if your attachments array really only has 4 items in it this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is really helpful. But when I use return this.data.Data.Summary.Attachment.some(attachment => attachment.typeId === '3'), it does not recognize json format in component file. And shows the error [ts] Property 'Data' does not exist. Thank you again.

Comment: @Sleepyhead ya I don't actually know what your component looks like and I was just assuming it had a `data` property. Hopefully this answer gives you the right idea and helps you come up with the correct solution for your use case.